# Why does this C code output a data which makes an interesting wave-like histogram?

Tags: c, matlab, histogram

Suppose that I use dictionary.txt (a dictionary of words) from [here](http://www.math.sjsu.edu/~foster/dictionary.txt), and this C code produces data like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void )
{
   FILE *dictionary = fopen ( "dictionary.txt", "r" );

   char entry[46];
   unsigned value = 0;

   while ( fscanf ( dictionary, "%s", entry ) != EOF ) {
      for ( int i = 0; entry[i]; ++i )
         value += entry[i];
      printf ( "%d"\n", value );
      value = 0;
   }

   fclose ( dictionary );

   return 0;
}
```

What this code does is, for every word in the dictionary it produces a value which is the sum of all ASCII values of each letter.

After compiling, I make a data.txt that collects all values on the terminal:

```
$ ./dictionary > data.txt
```

And on MATLAB:

```
fileID = fopen ( 'data.txt', 'r' );
formatSpec = '%u';
A = fscanf ( fileID, formatSpec );
fclose(fileID);

X = min(A):max(A);
hist ( A, X )
```

Which outputs a histogram that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: What kind of data is in `dictionary.txt`? How was it generated? To be honest I don't have any idea what you're asking here.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the C program reads one word at a time, adds the ASCII values of the letters, and writes that out as a decimal?

Comment: The answer completly dependes on the data. You are asking why some data you don't provide gives that histogram using some Matlab code you don't provide either, and some C code you don't explain

Comment: @LuisMendo, well we know it is a dictionary. ;-)

Comment: @A.Donda Yes... and that it contains "entries". Is each "entry" a word? (In which language?) A word with its definitions? :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo, true, the question is horribly underspecified. But I think it is still possible to come up with a guess regarding the histogram shape.

Comment: @A.Donda I wasn't sure how I can make the question more specific.  Care to make a suggestion?

Comment: @vxs8122, by giving the dictionary file and explaining your code I think your question is well specified now. Retracting my last comment. What do you think of the answer?

Comment: @A.Donde I think your answer is pretty solid and makes a lot more sense, but I am giving it a few more hours if other people wants to write their own answer too. :)

Comment: @vxs8122, no harm in upvoting my answer though, is there? ;-)

Comment: @A.Donde I already did shortly after you posted your answer :)

Comment: @vxs8122, ah ok, sorry & thanks! Let's see whether my update wins you over completely. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are plotting is a histogram of added-up ASCII values for white-space delimited strings in a text file. Following the name I assume it is a dictionary of English words.

English is mainly written in lower-case letters, which have ASCII-codes from 97 (a) to 122 (z), on average 110 (disregarding letter frequencies). The histogram shows peaks at distances of also about 110. The different peaks therefore correspond to words of different lengths. Discernible peaks seem to correspond to word lengths <s>from 1 to about 21 letters</s> **update:** 4 to 12 letters, with the most common word length being 8 letters.

The shape of the single peaks is roughly that of a normal distribution, which can be explained by the fact that different letters are "randomly" selected from the range of about 'a' to 'z'. Though these selections are surely not independent and identically distributed, still an effect like that described by the central limit theorem seems to take place.

---

**Update** after the question was edited: The file is indeed a list of English words, one per line, all written in lower-case letters. Some further analysis:

The ASCII values of the letters of all words taken together have the following absolute frequencies in the dictionary:
[image]
All occurring values are between 97 (a) and 122 (z). The mean value is 107.5 and the standard deviation is 6.89.

The frequencies of word lengths in the dictionary are:
[image]
My interpretation above that the most common word length is 8 turns out to be correct, but the range of word lengths is actually 4 to 12. The updated histogram in the question is consistent with that.

Now, if we simulate 4-, 8- and 12-letter words by randomly drawing from the pool of all letters, and then plot ASCII-sum histograms, this is the result:
[image]
It demonstrates that words of different lengths lead to peaks not just of different means (here: 430, 860, and 1290) but also of different widths (here: standard deviation 13.78, 19.49, and 23.91) and correspondingly of different heights.

The picture you see in your histogram is therefore a combination of the word length histogram and the sum-of-ASCII-values for different word lengths.

Comment: I was just typing that. And i was going to add that the width of each lobe seems to slightly increase with word length, which makes sense: the more letters per word the greater the standard deviation is, conditioned on that word length

Comment: This answer would gain you many points for the _mentalist_ badge, if we had one (as proposed by Rayryeng) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the dictionary is all lower-case.

1-letter words have a sum in the range 97-122.

2-letter words have a sum in the range 194-244.

3-letter words have a sum in the range 291-366.

4-letter words have a sum in the range 388-488.

5-letter words have a sum in the range 485-610.

Only now are the ranges starting to overlap, and even then only for words such as `zzzz` and `aaaaa`. The in between values are fewer or non-existent, unless words begin with a Capital or perhaps contain a hyphen. So the frequency peaks will be at multiples of about 110 as already said.

14 letter words have a sum in the range 1358-1708

15 letter words have a sum in the range 1455-1830

If each word length's histogram has a natural distribution, you can see this will show through the combined histogram.